# C# how can i use " in quotation marks

Tags: c#

```
stratInfo.Arguments = "RD /S /Q "C:\**" REG DELETE HKLM\SOFTWARE\**";
```

How can i use quotation marks in quotation marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotation marks are special symbols for beginning and ending strings. You need to add backslash (`\`) before them, if you need to have them inside a string, like so:

```
string text = "this is a string with \"quotation marks\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo stratInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        stratInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        stratInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        stratInfo.Arguments = "RD /S /Q \"C:\\******\" REG DELETE HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\************** /f REG DELETE HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\********** /f REG DELETE HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\**************** /f reg add \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\**************\" /v *********** /t REG_DWORD /d \"1\" /f reg add \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\******************\" /v ******** /d \"1\" /t REG_DWORD /f ";
        process.StartInfo = stratInfo;
        process.Start();
```

thanks to http://www.htmlescape.net/javaescape_tool.html